# Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php

So my problem is the error into the Title,there is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
  var search_term =$(this).val();
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"Mypage",
 data:{'fsearch':search_term},
 success:function(res){
  $("#food_search_result").html(res);
  console.log(res);
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
});
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->

<form method="post">
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "pass";
$databaseName = "dbname";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);


if(!empty($_POST["fsearch"])) {
$req = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE "%".$fsearch."%"');

$req->execute(array(
'title'=>'%'.$_POST['fsearch'].'%'
));
if($req->rowCount()==0){
echo 'Не бяха намерени резултати!';
}
else{
while($data=$req->fetch()){
?>
<div class="search-result">
    <img src="<?php echo $data['fimage']; ?>" class="fimage"/>
    <span class="result-title"><?php echo $data['title'] ;?></span><br>
    <span class="calories-total"><?php echo $data['calories total'] ;?></span><br>
</div>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

The code is used for instant search(google like).`$req` variable must get only information from db which is like variable search_term passed by jquery via ajax to php,and php must check if there are words or phrases which correspond to thing written in input field.

THANKS !

Comment: I added that to my code and it says 'mysqli_connect' not found

Comment: sorry it's `$connect = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);` you have to create connection in object-oriented fashion too

Answer (score 0):

```
$fsearch = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['fsearch']);
$req = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE %{$fsearch}%");
while($row=$req->fetch_array()){
    //output function  data: $row['title'], $row['calories total'], etc
}
```

[mysqli docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer to be more valuable for other users. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it,by adding a var $fsearch and fixing my query call,because "%".$fsearch."%"' was not right i writed '".$fsearch."%'" and as i said added the var $fsearch like that:`$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];`I tried is it working with

```
if($req) {
//code if it return true (if it is working)
}else{
//code if it return false(not working)
}
```

And now it returs true which mean query is working but gives me other

> error:mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Well i will ask other question for it.
Thanks for help !